# Aggregate matching array element that excludes original match

Tags: mongodb-query

I wish to link various records in different collections using a "link" collection.  At a later time, I want to find, for a given object, what it links to, but not include the given object ref.  Here's what I have so far:

link collection:

```
{ "id" : 1, "vertices" : [ { "id" : 1, "type" : "node" }, { "id" : 1, "type" : "entity" } ] }
{ "id" : 2, "vertices" : [ { "id" : 2, "type" : "node" }, { "id" : 1, "type" : "entity" } ] }
{ "id" : 3, "vertices" : [ { "id" : 3, "type" : "node" }, { "id" : 2, "type" : "entity" } ] }
{ "id" : 4, "vertices" : [ { "id" : 1, "type" : "node" }, { "id" : 1, "type" : "alert" } ] }
{ "id" : 5, "vertices" : [ { "id" : 1, "type" : "node" }, { "id" : 2, "type" : "entity" } ] }
{ "id" : 6, "vertices" : [ { "id" : 1, "type" : "node" }, { "id": 2, "type": "node" } ] }
```

So my first thought is to do this:

```
db.link.aggregate([
    {$match:{vertices:{$elemMatch:{id:1,type:"node"}}}},
    {$unwind:"$vertices"}
]);
```

which yields:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598ccc382381d7587032747c"), "id" : 1, "vertices" : { "id" : 1, "type" : "node" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598ccc382381d7587032747c"), "id" : 1, "vertices" : { "id" : 1, "type" : "entity" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598cd0f421d830c187071aca"), "id" : 4, "vertices" : { "id" : 1, "type" : "node" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598cd0f421d830c187071aca"), "id" : 4, "vertices" : { "id" : 1, "type" : "alert" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598dd404228b6d88470ed052"), "id" : 5, "vertices" : { "id" : 1, "type" : "node" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598dd404228b6d88470ed052"), "id" : 5, "vertices" : { "id" : 2, "type" : "entity" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598e201d720b766ed9f1a496"), "id" : 6, "vertices" : { "id" : 1, "type" : "node" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598e201d720b766ed9f1a496"), "id" : 6, "vertices" : { "id" : 2, "type" : "node" } }
```

A pretty good start, but I wish to get rid of the rows containing vertices with { id:1, type: "node" }.

So let's add another $match to the pipeline:

```
db.link.aggregate([
    {$match:{vertices:{$elemMatch:{id:1,type:"node"}}}},
    {$unwind: "$vertices"},
    {$match:{ 'vertices.id': {$ne:1}, 'vertices.type': {$ne:'node'} } }
]);
```

This yields the result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598dd404228b6d88470ed052"), "id" : 5, "vertices" : { "id" : 2, "type" : "entity" } }
```

when I really expected:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598ccc382381d7587032747c"), "id" : 1, "vertices" : { "id" : 1, "type" : "entity" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598cd0f421d830c187071aca"), "id" : 4, "vertices" : { "id" : 1, "type" : "alert" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598dd404228b6d88470ed052"), "id" : 5, "vertices" : { "id" : 2, "type" : "entity" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598e201d720b766ed9f1a496"), "id" : 6, "vertices" : { "id" : 2, "type" : "node" } }
```

So what I am I doing wrong in the second $match statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic strikes again!  For other's struggling with this:

```
db.link.aggregate([
    {$match:{vertices:{$elemMatch:{id:1,type:"node"}}}},
    {$unwind: "$vertices"},
    {$match:{$or: [
        {'vertices.type':{$ne:'node'}},
        {'vertices.id':{$ne:1}}
        ]}}
]);
```

gives me the desired results.